# Как ускорить парсинг курса валют?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Есть программа, которая парсит курс евро и доллара.
Все прекрасно работает, но ощутимо медленно: работа функции занимает от 3 до 5 секунд...

```py
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


def get_wal():
    headers = {
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "Host":"myfin.by:443",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
    }

    body = get('https://myfin.by/currency/minsk', headers=headers)
    for_bs = body.text
    soup = bs(for_bs, 'html.parser')

    usd_span = soup.find_all('span', {'class':'bl_usd_ex'})
    usd = usd_span[0].text
    eur_span = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'bl_eur_ex'})
    eur = eur_span[0].text

    return usd, eur
```

Как я могу это ускорить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Развивая тему мобильной версии из [ответа CrazyElf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1272200/420098):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://m.myfin.by/currency/minsk'        # адрес мобильной версии
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

usd = soup.find('div', class_='bl_usd_ex').text  # тут котировки в div-ах,
eur = soup.find('div', class_='bl_eur_ex').text  # не span, как в десктопной

print(f'usd: {usd}, eur: {eur}')
```

Тест времени выполнения:

```
$ time python sample_handing.py 
usd: 2.5864, eur: 3.1186

real    0m0,881s
user    0m0,266s
sys     0m0,012s
```

Вариант с использованием lxml в качестве парсера:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
```

еще немного ускорит обработку:

```
$ time python sample_handing.py
usd: 2.5996, eur: 3.1235

real    0m0,750s
user    0m0,378s
sys     0m0,016s
```

Answer (score 4):

Видимо, у вас совсем медленный сервер, где вы запускаете скрипт, либо днём больше нагрузка на сайт. Я сейчас пробовал через Google Colab, основное время занимает загрузка страницы с сайта, с этим вы ничего не можете сделать. Если только вдруг у них есть API или мобильная версия, но я сходу не нашёл. Единственное, что можно сделать - поменять парсер на `lxml`, он немного быстрее:

```
soup = bs(for_bs, 'lxml')
```

С этим парсером в Colab получается около 0.8с - загрузка страницы, и ещё 0.5с - парсинг BS, итого примерно 1.5с, но и с тем парсером, который был указан у вас, в Colab была 1.7с загрузка примерно.